# MySql - Three tables joined and grouped by one column from one table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have four tables all in all,

tbluser,
tblstudentlead,
tblcalls,
tbldocusin

I want to group the results of my queries by tbluser.id

here is my query:

```
select t.fk, MAX(u.firstname) as Name, t.Leads, t.Calls, t.Docu
from
(


SELECT salesuserId as fk, COUNT(id) Leads
FROM tblstudentlead 
WHERE createdon
BETWEEN  '2015-01-01'
AND  '2016-01-01'
GROUP BY salesuserId


union all
SELECT createdBy as fk, COUNT(id) Calls
FROM tblcalls
WHERE createdon
BETWEEN  '2015-01-01'
AND  '2016-01-01'
GROUP BY createdBy


union all
SELECT createdBy as fk, COUNT(id) Docu
FROM tbldocusin
WHERE createdon
BETWEEN  '2015-01-01'
AND  '2016-01-01'
AND status = 'completed'
GROUP BY createdBy
) t

inner join tbluser u on (t .fk=u.id)
group by u.id
order by u.id asc
```

But it only gives me this result

```
fk | Name | Leads
```

The result I need is:

```
fk | Name | Leads | Docu
```

Thanks hope you help me

Answer (score 0):

You will probably be better off using subqueries if I understand your question correctly.  Here's an example:

```
select u.id, 
       u.firstname as Name, 
       (select count(id) Leads
        from tblstudentlead t
        where t.salesuserId = u.id and createdon between '2015-01-01' and '2016-01-01') as Leads,
       (select count(id) Calls
        from tblcalls c
        where c.createdBy = u.id and createdon between '2015-01-01' and '2016-01-01') as Calls,
       (select count(id) Docu
        from tbldocusin d
        where d.createdBy = u.id createdon between '2015-01-01' and '2016-01-01') as Docu
from tbluser u 
order by u.id
```

Alternatively you could use the subquery in a `join`:

```
select u.id, 
       u.firstname as Name, 
       l.Leads,
       c.Calls,
       d.Docu
from tbluser u join
    (select salesuserId as id, count(id) Leads
    from tblstudentlead 
    where createdon between '2015-01-01' and '2016-01-01'
    group by salesuserId) l on u.id = l.id join 
    (select createdBy as id, count(id) Calls
    from tblcalls 
    where createdon between '2015-01-01' and '2016-01-01'
    group by createdBy) c on u.id = c.id join 
    (select createdBy as id, count(id) Calls
    from tbldocusin 
    where createdon between '2015-01-01' and '2016-01-01'
    group by createdBy) d on u.id = d.id 
order by u.id
```